# Change background-position when using parallax

Tags: css

I'm using parallax.js so that some divs on my webpage have a fixed background with a parallax effect (for those who don't know what parallax is : http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/).

I have a div who is supposed to change height right above a div with a parallax background. When I click on a button, content is revealed and the height of the div changes but the problem is content overflows on the parallax background. 
I guess it is because the parallax background has a fixed position determined when the page is created, so when the page changes the position has already been defined.

Here's a picture of my problem :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2EJV.jpg

In the first screen, I haven't clicked on the button to reveal content yet. You can see the "SKILLS" on a parallax background.
In the 2nd screen, I clicked on the button so the content revealed pushes down everything on the page and instead of having the white background wrapping all the content in the "FORMATION" part, the content overflows on the parallax background.

Does anyone know how to make the parallax background change position as the content above expands ?

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [MCVE]

Comment: Sorry I thought I was clear enough. I edited my post, but I can't really show you my code because it's way too long.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve my problem :
When I click on the button, I use a callback function to recalculate where the parallax background is.

```
$("#detailsSchoolMD").slideToggle(function(){
$(window).trigger('resize.px.parallax');
});
```